# Do we need to reboot Ubuntu server after un-installing tomcat6

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat6, ubuntu-10.04

i am on ubuntu 10.04 server, having tomcat6. because of some reasons i had to un-install it so i used

```
apt-get purge tomcat6
```

it removed tomcat and config files.

now i am trying to install tomcat6 again, using

```
apt-get install tomcat6
```

it says

```
Setting up tomcat6 (6.0.24-2ubuntu1.9) ...
Adding system user `tomcat6' (UID 109) ...
Adding new user `tomcat6' (UID 109) with group `tomcat6' ...
Not creating home directory `/usr/share/tomcat6'.
* Starting Tomcat servlet engine tomcat6            [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript tomcat6, action "start" failed.
```

looked into log

```
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 1: FileHandler is closed or not yet initialized, unable to log [Dec 2, 2011 7:39:08 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
```

I am not tomcat expert, so not sure should i have to reboot server to install tomcat6 again. can anyone please help?

[EDIT] - as suggested by Erick Robertson i uploaded same question on [stackfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/337020/do-we-need-to-reboot-ubuntu-server-after-un-installing-tomcat6). As i am looking my answer as soon as possible, you can answer at any location

[EDIT-2] - i have deleted its duplicate on serverfault. Got it working, as mentioned by Mike, i was missing 1 step of killing processes `kill -9 pid1 pid2` . Thanks very much Mike

Comment: Voted to move to serverfault.

Comment: @bee You don't need to cross-post your question; moderators have the ability to migrate your question from one StackExchange site to another.

Comment: You should have a line earlier in the log stating the error, the log fragment in your question does not include the root cause.

Comment: @Mike- Thanks for sharing, i did not know that great feature.  So you mean i should delete my question from stackfault

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were looking into this myself, I would run `sudo apt-get remove --purge tomcat6` (again).  Once that was completed, I would run `ps -eaf | grep tomcat | grep -v -e grep` to check for any stray running Tomcat processes.  Once I had confirmed that Tomcat was no longer running, I would reinstall: `sudo apt-get install tomcat6`.

Comment: don't you think tomcat processes should be grepped as `grep java`?

Comment: i used <pre><code> apt-get remove --purge tomcat6 </code></pre> it says The group `code` tomcat6 does not exist.
dpkg: warning: while removing tomcat6, directory '/etc/tomcat6/Catalina/localhost' not empty so not removed.
dpkg: warning: while removing tomcat6, directory '/etc/tomcat6/Catalina' not empty so not removed.
dpkg: warning: while removing tomcat6, directory '/etc/tomcat6' not empty so not removed.`code`. Should i run `code`rm -Rf /etc/tomcat6`code`

Comment: @Oleg: No, in fact, I do not think that tomcat processes should be grepped as java from experience...   @bee: Yes, I would `rm -rf /etc/tomcat6` in that case.

Comment: I used **rm -rf /etc/tomcat6**. bit when i run **ps -eaf | grep tomcat | grep -v -e grep** it gives so many processes

Comment: e.g. `/usr/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/share/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties`  `-Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat6 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/share/tomcat6/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start`   ..............

Comment: If you do not have the `tomcat6` package installed anymore, yet you still have processes running, you should kill them.  The above `grep` command will get you their pids (second column of the grep output).  Just run `sudo kill -9 pid1 pid2` etc (replace pid1 and pid2 with your actual pids.  You can put as many pids on the line as you want.)

Comment: @Mike - thanks very much, your killing method ( `kill -9 pid1 pid2` ) was great its working. Thanks again